# I'm glad you do/ I'm glad you like the painting (i've drawn) -- meaning difference

Tags: auxiliary-verbs, ellipsis, sentence-choice

If someone tells you they really like the painting you've drawn.

Could you respond to their telling you that, saying **"I'm glad you do."**, instead of **"I'm glad you like the painting"**

Comment: I went to the doctor about this cough. -- I'm glad you did.   I like your tie. -- I'm glad you do.   I'm in a good mood today.  -- I'm glad you are.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As part of a conversation you can use the sentence 'I'm glad you do' to show that you are happy about a something the other person says about themselves.

Saying 'I'm glad you like the painting' doesn't need a prior statement from the other person; for example, the other person may have said nothing but you can tell from what their face that they like the painting.

Both have the same meaning assuming the other person has said something about how they like the painting.